Confusion about Kunneth Formula in Weibel 3.6.1
I am referring to the following in Theorem in Weibel:

So I am confused about the last two lines of the proof:
so applying Tor to the second last equation yield the exact sequence in the last equation, but why is the last term $0$ (i.e. this notation seems to be suggesting there is an isomoprhism between $Z_n\otimes M$ and $d(P_{n+1})\otimes M$, which is not necessarily true)?
Secondly, I don't see how the flat resolution in the last equation yield the statement we want to prove?

Please give the title of the book : there are several books with author's name Weibel !

@JeanMarie It is Weibel's "H-Book"; "An introduction to homological algebra"

Yes, this is Weibel's Homological Algebra.

Allow me to use "$Q$" for the chain complex of flat $R$-modules. I'll talk through the proof again and emphasise the bits that confused you.
From the long exact sequence in homology associated to the short exact sequence of complexes: $$0\to Z_\bullet\otimes M\to Q_\bullet\otimes M\to d(Q)\otimes M\to0$$Which is exact because $d(Q)$ is flat, we get exact sequences - for each $n$: $$(\ast):\quad\,d(Q_{n+1})\otimes M\overset{\delta_{n+1}}{\longrightarrow}Z_n\otimes M\overset{\alpha}{\longrightarrow}H_n(Q\otimes M)\overset{\beta}{\longrightarrow}
d(Q_n)\otimes M\overset{\delta_n}{\longrightarrow}Z_{n-1}\otimes M$$
The maps $\alpha,\beta$ are the obvious ones. Notice $\beta$ doesn't have to be zero, even though it may feel like it should - because it's applying the boundary operators which define $Q\otimes M$, so it "should" kill cycle classes in $H_n(Q\otimes M)$ - but, e.g., $d(q)\otimes m$ can be zero in $Q\otimes M$ without being zero in $d(Q)\otimes M$; $d(Q)\otimes M\longrightarrow Q\otimes M$ isn't necessarily injective. This kind of 'weirdness' is exactly why the $\mathrm{Tor}$ terms appear.
What are the maps $\delta_\bullet$? If you think about the definition of $\delta$ in a long exact sequence in homology, it is just the map $j\otimes1$ if $j:d(Q_n)\hookrightarrow Z_{n-1}$ is the subobject inclusion.
Now, if we think about $(\ast)$ hard enough we know it implies the following short exact sequence: $$0\to\mathrm{Cok}(\delta_{n+1})\overset{\alpha'}{\longrightarrow}H_n(Q\otimes M)\overset{\beta'}{\longrightarrow}\mathrm{Ker}(\delta_n)\to0$$You can always do this kind of replacement of a long exact sequence into many short ones. What Weibel does in the final two lines is calculate these kernels and cokernels. That's exactly the same thing as:

"The homology of the sequence $(\ast\ast):\quad\,0\to d(Q_n)\otimes M\overset{\delta_n}{\longrightarrow}Z_{n-1}\otimes M\to0$"

You said something about isomorphisms; I think you were thinking $(\ast\ast)$ is exact, but this isn't usually true. Don't mistake the appearance of zeroes for an indication the sequence is (short) exact! Its homology is exactly what we care about and is probably nontrivial, i.e. the sequence $(\ast\ast)$ is inexact. And because $0\to d(Q_n)\to Z_{n-1}\to H_{n-1}(Q)\to0$ is a flat resolution, this homology is exactly $H_{n-1}(Q)\otimes M$ (for the cokernel of $\delta_n$) and $\mathrm{Tor}^1_R(H_{n-1}(Q),M)$ (for the kernel of $\delta_n$).

Thanks for the answer, yeah the notation in the book was a little confusing.
